# BlankNullSequence (___) when input variable is Null

Tags: pattern-matching, core-language

```
f[x___] := Plus[x, -x]
```

`f[Null]` gives output as `0`

`f[]` gives output as `-1`

`f[, ]` gives output as `2 Null - Null^2`

I thought the three shall be equivalent.

Further more,

`f[{}]` gives output as `{}`

`f[{, }]` gives output as `{0, 0}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several core language features have involved in here.

First of all, `f[]` isn't equivalent to `f[Null]`. Indeed, as mentioned in **Details** section of document of `Null`:

> Expressions like f[e<sub>1</sub>, , e<sub>2</sub>] are interpreted to have `Null` between each pair of adjacent commas.

But as you've seen, one-argument case is not covered here. Let's check the `FullForm` of the code (when you feel confused about the core language, always check the `FullForm`!):

```
Clear[fff]
fff[] // FullForm
fff[, ] // FullForm
fff[, ,] // FullForm
```

[image]

As we can see, when there's no comma, the *blank* isn't interpreted as `Null`, it simply means no argument is there.

The second important thing is, one might roughly think that `-x` means something like "a minus sign is prepended", but it's not true. Once again, let's check the `FullForm`:

```
Clear[x]
-x // FullForm
```

[image]

What will happen if no argument is passed to x in `Times[-1, x]`? As mentioned in **Details** section of `Times`:

> `Times[x]` is `x`.

Similarly, as mentioned in **Details** section of `Plus`:

> `Plus[x]` is `x`.

So `f[]` will evaluate to

```
Plus[Times[-1]]
(* -1 *)
```

`f[Null]` will evaluate to

```
Plus[Null, Times[-1, Null]]
(* 0 *)
```

`f[Null, Null]` will evaluate to

```
Plus[Null, Null, Times[-1, Null, Null]]
(* 2 Null - Null^2 *)
```

There's nothing special in `f[{}]` and `f[{,}]` so I'd like to stop here.